# How can I override /customer/account, the Newsletter part?

Tags: magento2

How can I override `/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml`?
[image]

Specifically the Newsletter part, I'd like to place my own MailChimp list there

I've tried to copy the template to `app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Infortis_Ultimo/Magento_Customer/web/template/account/dashboard/info.phtml`
as well as `app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Infortis_Ultimo/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml` but it's not taking effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your `info.phtml`

from :

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

to :

> app/design/frontend/Infortis/ultimo/Magento_Customer/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml

Comment: Thank you! That worked! For future references, how can I figure this out? Is there a way to actually know where to copy files?